# Generate .txt file with javascript without using activex and local server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to generate text file with the help of javascript which can read,write and append into this file.Is it possible without using activex and local server?
I am waiting for response.Thanks.

Comment: please try to update your question with code.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to generate a response to user input on a web page. That's a way too big a subject for someone to write up for you here. It's also very much dependent on your chosen server platform. With all due respect, I think you need to Google for a tutorial on this one! That way, you can start to learn some of the principles involved.

Comment: @MusakkhirSayyed I had modified question.Please take a look at it.

Comment: @BenHillier Completely agree. But I want this functionality.Thanks.

Comment: What web server are you using? Since you said python, it's possibly flask: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms

Comment: You could also be using old fashioned CGI: http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/dynamic.html

Comment: There are many other possibilities. But I've got the impression your starting from scratch here. You really do need to Google for a tutorial for your particular server setup. Good luck!

Comment: @BenHillier Thanks for your response.As i have constraint to work without server.Please refer my current modified question.

Comment: HI @BenHillier. I forgot to update the answer.I had not get exact solution but yes you can do this with localstorage functionality of browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to write an HTML file that alters a local file on your computer? I'm afraid that's impossible. There's no browser that will allow its javascript engine write access to local files; doing so would be a massive security risk. Malicious websites all over the world could change the contents of your computer.

It's not clear to me why you're trying to do this, but I think you have to look a bit further that just some local HTML.